# Hikaripool : No new connections are added to the pool when old connections are expired

Tags: spring-boot, azure-sql-database, hikaricp

I have a Hikari pool for AzureSQL database. The pool size is 75. Initialy it add 75 conncetions to the pool, when connections are closed, its adding new connectiosn to the pool.

Pool configuration is shown below.

But after some time we see the total number of connections in the pool goes down. When connections are cloased no new connections are added to the pool. Finally the *total* number of connections reach ZERO.

Please refer the logs below. The logs clearly shows this behaviour.

Once total connection is ZERO, threads wait for connection and finally times out with error *Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms*

Below is the connection pool configuration.

```
MyConnectionPool - configuration:
allowPoolSuspension.............false
autoCommit......................true
catalog.........................none
connectionInitSql...............none
connectionTestQuery.............none
connectionTimeout...............30000
dataSource......................none
dataSourceClassName.............none
dataSourceJNDI..................none
dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
driverClassName................."com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
healthCheckProperties...........{}
healthCheckRegistry.............none
idleTimeout.....................300000
initializationFailFast..........true
initializationFailTimeout.......1
isolateInternalQueries..........false
jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:sqlserver://<SERVER>:<PORT>;database=<database>
leakDetectionThreshold..........0
maxLifetime.....................600000
maximumPoolSize.................100
metricRegistry..................none
metricsTrackerFactory...........none
minimumIdle.....................75
password........................<masked>
poolName........................"MyConnectionPool"
readOnly........................false
registerMbeans..................false
scheduledExecutor...............none
scheduledExecutorService........internal
schema..........................none
threadFactory...................internal
transactionIsolation............default
username........................"dbusername"
validationTimeout...............5000
```

Logs

```
2019-05-15 12:55:28.572 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133785 ClientConnectionId: 5a2d0116-a8f9-4cd2-aab7-3138db1ea627: (connection was evicted)
2019-05-15 12:55:28.615  INFO 17 --- [onnection adder] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
2019-05-15 12:55:28.661 DEBUG 17 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - Added connection ConnectionID:133873 ClientConnectionId: 1e729748-5f80-4a88-8545-e0ca16d1a34b
2019-05-15 12:55:28.661 DEBUG 17 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - After adding stats (total=76, active=1, idle=75, waiting=0)
2019-05-15 12:55:42.192 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133798 ClientConnectionId: d3816606-8cb5-4b5e-8ca0-771fa877e2a2: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:55:45.478 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133797 ClientConnectionId: b464f02e-eed6-4f33-9b2a-c69e894c1611: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:55:45.484  INFO 17 --- [onnection adder] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
2019-05-15 12:55:45.530 DEBUG 17 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - Added connection ConnectionID:133874 ClientConnectionId: a02ef032-3a41-429c-b328-b0cd9b74ba15
2019-05-15 12:55:46.482 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133796 ClientConnectionId: cb17a32d-234a-40a3-b0fb-617cac5158a1: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:55:46.486  INFO 17 --- [onnection adder] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
2019-05-15 12:55:46.552 DEBUG 17 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - Added connection ConnectionID:133875 ClientConnectionId: e3731254-71ac-4fd8-b304-19c71ebad2b6
2019-05-15 12:55:47.131 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133801 ClientConnectionId: 1357d6e1-20ce-4a84-8143-2fb095fa7dbb: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:55:47.136  INFO 17 --- [onnection adder] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
2019-05-15 12:55:47.191 DEBUG 17 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - Added connection ConnectionID:133876 ClientConnectionId: 6ba7a1e7-52df-4719-a95c-fb5d67711aaa
2019-05-15 12:55:48.834 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133800 ClientConnectionId: 3f872d11-1af4-47de-9e8c-51f8801ed750: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:55:48.838  INFO 17 --- [onnection adder] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
2019-05-15 12:55:48.890 DEBUG 17 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - Added connection ConnectionID:133877 ClientConnectionId: ae989f7c-d3fa-4ff0-9305-ebbbf393f558
2019-05-15 12:55:50.271 DEBUG 17 --- [ool housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - Before cleanup stats (total=75, active=0, idle=75, waiting=0)
2019-05-15 12:55:50.271 DEBUG 17 --- [ool housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - After cleanup  stats (total=75, active=0, idle=75, waiting=0)
2019-05-15 12:55:50.955 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133799 ClientConnectionId: c71a7b65-b306-4385-81f5-6f264feb2d7b: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:55:50.959  INFO 17 --- [onnection adder] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
2019-05-15 12:55:51.026 DEBUG 17 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - Added connection ConnectionID:133878 ClientConnectionId: 7db54029-a6a1-47e5-bae7-dc42c5a3cd5b
2019-05-15 12:55:53.232 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133803 ClientConnectionId: e67f2293-726c-4651-afdb-c5d86cbbf208: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:55:53.237  INFO 17 --- [onnection adder] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
2019-05-15 12:55:54.994 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133802 ClientConnectionId: 51fd57be-67a2-4a85-ad77-396e672a0bfb: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:55:56.913 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133804 ClientConnectionId: b6c81baf-0bf6-4002-9075-f1311c5eeb47: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:00.639 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133805 ClientConnectionId: 5b5abe04-23ac-468f-93be-1424b4f838ea: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:07.080 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133806 ClientConnectionId: 052f89a1-c9ba-4e8d-81e8-af884b19a260: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:07.515 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133807 ClientConnectionId: f5caa695-6c10-4edc-bf0d-9dc9a5bebbcd: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:09.517 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133809 ClientConnectionId: 3eb98771-b145-4788-be3f-0fe1ed20bc2e: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:11.496 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133808 ClientConnectionId: 3cb59458-f4ee-44f0-b89a-c041bab47f05: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:19.231 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133811 ClientConnectionId: e9ef4658-e86d-4d9d-b277-fe184bf91e1b: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:20.271 DEBUG 17 --- [ool housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - Before cleanup stats (total=66, active=0, idle=66, waiting=0)
2019-05-15 12:56:20.272 DEBUG 17 --- [ool housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - After cleanup  stats (total=66, active=0, idle=66, waiting=0)
2019-05-15 12:56:21.899 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133810 ClientConnectionId: 225d1741-f9ee-4eee-9781-6fedde1f58d1: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:26.133 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133816 ClientConnectionId: 6d2519eb-d5d2-40ee-b21e-861c65469ae7: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:28.199 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133812 ClientConnectionId: 9c6ed374-e198-49e4-993d-f941eafd90c8: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:33.284 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133814 ClientConnectionId: c228ddbc-a681-4840-b030-b21c1784ab44: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:34.444 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133817 ClientConnectionId: 166f9e66-dea6-4fdc-875e-8fd6a3e8d63e: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:35.498 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133813 ClientConnectionId: 19c35284-2e48-4dd9-b15e-a399693da5f4: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:38.204 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133815 ClientConnectionId: 55ec82d6-1768-4dec-a9c6-5066e5a49010: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:43.244 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133818 ClientConnectionId: f6bd0e08-82e7-4a3b-855b-b687b637cc54: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:43.401 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133821 ClientConnectionId: 2d231ef2-3bda-48d2-b273-bb6baa6460eb: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:45.232 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133819 ClientConnectionId: f3d57bb6-1216-495a-ab96-66037700a410: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:49.309 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133822 ClientConnectionId: 67e255ee-3b2e-4b60-8f92-29f392545365: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:56:50.272 DEBUG 17 --- [ool housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - Before cleanup stats (total=55, active=0, idle=55, waiting=0)
2019-05-15 12:56:50.272 DEBUG 17 --- [ool housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - After cleanup  stats (total=55, active=0, idle=55, waiting=0)
2019-05-15 12:56:51.507 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133820 ClientConnectionId: a9f80ef0-4dd8-4e89-b825-5b00290f7139: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:57:04.483 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133824 ClientConnectionId: 98796f7d-76e5-425c-a2eb-e43f7baf64df: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:57:05.515 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133825 ClientConnectionId: 60f39474-91b3-4fa3-8659-5d20507be6eb: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:57:06.123 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133823 ClientConnectionId: 890ea5e0-cb0e-4411-9d9f-829cb6d9cba6: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:57:12.578 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133826 ClientConnectionId: 4742bb54-0efb-424b-a369-e3fb927ea2ab: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:57:20.272 DEBUG 17 --- [ool housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - Before cleanup stats (total=50, active=0, idle=50, waiting=0)
2019-05-15 12:57:20.273 DEBUG 17 --- [ool housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - After cleanup  stats (total=50, active=0, idle=50, waiting=0)
2019-05-15 12:57:28.559 DEBUG 17 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : MyConnectionPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:133827 ClientConnectionId: d7a702e4-0a2e-4768-b402-23655fa1c9af: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-05-15 12:57:50.273 DEBUG 17 --- [ool housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - Before cleanup stats (total=49, active=0, idle=49, waiting=0)
2019-05-15 12:57:50.273 DEBUG 17 --- [ool housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : MyConnectionPool - After cleanup  stats (total=49, active=0, idle=49, waiting=0)
```

Wondering if anyone here has faced this issue before and can help me with the solution.

Comment: The configuration you show and the log output don't match. You state you have 75 connections, judging from the configuration only min/max 10. So how are you configuring the pool (looks like you aren't using the Spring Boot defaults then).

Comment: @M.Deinum My bad, corrected the configuration.

Comment: @RathishkumarNair  - Did you get a solution to your above issue.Im also having a similar issue